# two jquery conflicts in the code, the placement make the difference

Tags: jquery, html, popup, popupwindow

I am having a weird problem. 
I am developing a product display page. where I need to use a quick view button. for quick view I user [pop-up-overlay](http://vast-engineering.github.io/jquery-popup-overlay/).
This pop-up-overlay is using  jquery

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery Popup Overlay -->
<script src="js/jquery.popupoverlay.js"></script>
```

The problem is if i place jquery.min.js at the top of popupoverlay, then pop is working fine, but my other control's jquery is not working, like textbox-keyup event, radio-change event.
    But if i place the jquery.min.js next to poperoverlay then the popup is not opening.
Please help me to solve the issue

Comment: jQuery has to come first as the other scripts rely on it. You haven't shown where you define the keyup event on your textbox, but that too *has* to come *after* jQuery is included.

Answer (score 0):

jQuer.min.js will come at the top because all functions related to jquery rely on it and always remember that if you are using two different jquery file then use $.noConflict(); or jQuery.noConflict();.

Answer (score 0):

If it's for modal/popup functions have you considered pulling in a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation? They integrate nicely with jQuery without the conflict headaches!